# Angular : http POST with body

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to call the http post call in angular with a body but I am not getting the response.

```
callAddGroupAPI(formId, groupJSON){
   let json = {
       "group":groupJSON
   }

    this.http.post(this.apiURL+'AddGroup/'+formId+'/3',{body:json}).subscribe(message => {
      alert("success");
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
 }
```

where '**this.apiURL/AddGroup/formId/groupId**' is my URL
and I want to send some JSON body where '**key = group**' and "**value=someJSON**"

[image: I am attaching the postman screenshot below]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add  HttpHeaders  in your post request like https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
 create(request: RequestData) {
 return this.http.post(this.shopService.getShopBaseUrl() + 
 'Requests', request, {
 headers: new HttpHeaders()
 .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem its about body format. 
[image]

In postman your body its **form-data**, and in Angular if you don't define http body as **form-data**, for default it's a **raw** body, with a JSON object.

I think to revolve your problem you need to change your code to:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.set('group',groupJSON);
//or
body.append('group',groupJSON);

this.http.post(this.apiURL+'AddGroup/'+formId+'/3',body).subscribe(message => {
  alert("success");
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }
)
```

Comment: so, Is that **x.set()** or **body.set** ??

Comment: body.set() sorry